# Ruamel yaml bad dump

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a Python script which tries to generate a README from a "main.yml" file.

I can dump each line of the YML stream, but at each line, ruamel.yaml seems to add a line with "..." string.

My Python :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
import argparse
import ruamel.yaml

ROLES_PATH="../"
DESC_SCRIPT = 'This program will try to generate MD documentation from variables files of an Ansible role'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = DESC_SCRIPT)
parser.add_argument("-r", "--role", help="specify the name of existing role")
if len(sys.argv)<2:
   parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
   sys.exit(1)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.role:
   README=(ROLES_PATH+args.role+"/README.md")
   if os.path.isfile(README):
      print(sys.argv[0]+": README.md already exists for %s" % args.role)
      print(sys.argv[0]+": Exiting... ")
      sys.exit(2)
   if os.path.isdir(ROLES_PATH+args.role):
      print(sys.argv[0]+": Role found")
      print(sys.argv[0]+": Selected role is %s" % args.role)

      readme_file = open(README, 'w')
      readme_file.write("Role Name\n=========\n%s\n\nRequirements\n------------\n- Debian\n\nRole variables (default)\n--------------\n\n" % args.role)

      yml = ruamel.yaml
      yml.YAML.explicit_start = True
      yml.YAML.default_flow_style = None
      yml.YAML.encoding = "utf-8"
      yml.YAML.allow_unicode = True
      yml.YAML.errors = "strict"

      readme_file = open(README, 'a+')
      with open(ROLES_PATH+args.role+"/defaults/main.yml", "r") as stream:
         code = yml.load(stream, Loader=yml.RoundTripLoader)
         print(code)
         for line in code:
            print(type(line))
            print("Line : %s" % line)
            yml.dump(line, readme_file, Dumper=yml.RoundTripDumper)
```

My main.yml :

```
---
apache_datadir: '/var/www'
apache_security_configuration: '/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf'
apache_default_vhost: '/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf'
apache_mpm: event
apache_mod_list:
  - headers
  - ssl
  - rewrite
```

My README generated :

```
Role Name
=========
ansible-apache

Requirements
------------
- Debian

Role variables (default)
--------------

apache_datadir
...
apache_security_configuration
...
apache_default_vhost
...
apache_mpm
... 
apache_mod_list
...
```

I don't see why "..." is generated at each line. 
I tried to do something like  "if line is '...'" , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where did you pick up doing `yml.YAML.explicit_start = True`? That is really very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you dump a single plain, folded or literal scalar without indentation (i.e. when they are the only node to be dumped), then `ruamel.yaml` adds these end-of-document markers. This is inherited behaviour from PyYAML.

Internally this is because the attribute `open_ended` is set on the `Emitter` instance, and although you can rewrite the methods there not to do this, it is far easier to just write a string to `readme_file` instead of dumping the string as YAML:

```
if isinstance(line, str):
    readme_file.write(line + '\n')
else:
    yml.dump(line, readme_file, Dumper=yml.RoundTripDumper)
```

If you know up-front that all your `line` values are going to be strings, then you don't need to use `dump` at all.

You also seem to combine old style loading/dumping with the new `ruamel.yaml` API. This:

```
  yml = ruamel.yaml
  yml.YAML.explicit_start = True
  yml.YAML.default_flow_style = None
  yml.YAML.encoding = "utf-8"
  yml.YAML.allow_unicode = True
  yml.YAML.errors = "strict"
```

has no effect on `yml.dump`. What you probably want to do is:

```
  yml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
  yml.explicit_start = True
  yml.default_flow_style = None 
  yml.encoding = "utf-8"     # default when using YAML() or YAML(typ="rt")
  yml.allow_unicode = True   # always default in the new API
  yml.errors = "strict"
```

and then dump with `yml.dump(data, file_pointer)` (i.e. without `RoundTripDumper`)